# python: read integer's from stream step by step

Tags: python, input, stream

I can in Python:

```
n = int(input())
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

I can in c++:

```
int main()
{
    int n, x;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        somthing(x)
    }

}
```

How to write it on Python (3.x)? Can I handle the numbers in the flow without saving all in list?

Input data (for example):

```
6
1 4 4 4 1 1
```

Can I use sys.stdin?

UPD:

Ok, I wrote this:

```
import sys

n = int(input())
i = 0
c = ""
s = ""
while i < n:
    c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if c in [" ","\n"]:
        x = int(s)
        somthing(x)
        s = ""
        i += 1
    else:
        s += c
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer? I've edited it.

Comment: Yes. Your answer is wrong

Comment: The input data format is unclear. Is it line oriented or no?

Comment: Input: two string. First: N, second M1 M2 M3 ... MN

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't special-case such a specific form of input for you. By default, the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function then reads a line from input (delimited by newline character) and converts it to a string.

You'll have to use the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to separate the values.

Comment: `input().split()` returns a list. Your solution stores everything in the list.

Comment: @vaultah - The OP simply wants to handle each number. I have a feeling OP might be a beginner, knows only one way of accepting an input using list comprehension `a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]` and does not properly understand how to use loops in python.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro: AFAICT the OP wants to translate that C++ code to Python.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro: the type of `x` in the C++ code is `int`, the type of `a` in your answer is `str`.

Comment: @vaultah - You have an eye for minor details. Edited the answer. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Btw @user2704006 seems to be using Python 3. If it's true, then you'd replace `xrange` with `range`. If they use Python 2, then the original version (`a = input()`) of your answer was correct.

Comment: For example your code write:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 4 4 4 1 1'